# Node.js: Google Analytics API: How do I make authorized read-only Management API requests with a "service account"?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-analytics-api, service-accounts

I'm creating an LED grid ticker run on a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org) that will collect Google Analytics data via the Google Analytics API using Node.js. It will tally up counts from multiple websites then scrolling the stats across the grid.

I could use help listing account items via the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/), specifically account id, property ids, and view ids to save on manual work. I'm getting errors in this area (see below).

This seemed like the job for a `Service Account`. After setting up a Google Cloud project [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/projects), then setting up a service account [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts), I added the email address contained within the downloaded authorization as a property user (read/analyze permissions) where applicable in Google Analytics admin settings. With this, I can successfully retrieve Analytics data for a known view ID (looked up manually in Google Analytics admin, ID shown on a view settings page), with this:

```
'use strict';

//////////////
// includes //
//////////////

var google = require('googleapis');
var fs = require('fs');
var Promise = require('promise');

//////////////
// settings //
//////////////

//the service account auth file downloaded from Google Cloud
var serviceAccountInfoPath = './secrets.json';

//view id with 'ga:' prefix
//I want this to soon be an array of ids looked up by an authenticated API requested
var viewID = 'ga:999999999'; 

////////
// go //
////////

// go get it all
var go = function() {
    loadServiceAccountInfo()
    .then(function(serviceAccountInfo) {
        return getJwtClient(serviceAccountInfo);
    })
    .then(function(jwtClient) {
        var client = jwtClient;
        var analytics = google.analytics('v3');
        return getThisYearViewAnalytics(client, analytics, viewID);
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log('total users: ' + result.totalsForAllResults["ga:users"]);
        console.log('total sessions: ' + result.totalsForAllResults["ga:pageviews"]);
        console.log('total pageviews: ' + result.totalsForAllResults["ga:sessions"]);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("go promise chain failed", error);
    });
};

// load the Google service account login details
var loadServiceAccountInfo = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(serviceAccountInfoPath, 'utf8', function(error, serviceAccountInfoData) {
            if(error) {
                console.log('loadServiceAccountInfo failed: ' + error);
                reject(error);
            } else {
                var serviceAccountInfo = JSON.parse(serviceAccountInfoData);
                resolve(serviceAccountInfo);
            }
        });
    });
};

//return a an authenticated Google API client
var getJwtClient = function(serviceAccountInfo) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(serviceAccountInfo.client_email, null, serviceAccountInfo.private_key, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'], null);
        jwtClient.authorize(function (error, tokens) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('getJwtClient failed: ' + error);
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(jwtClient);
            }
        });
    });
};

//this is a test query to get the last year of data for a single view id
var getThisYearViewAnalytics = function(client, analytics, viewID) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        analytics.data.ga.get({
            'auth': client,
            'ids': viewID,
            'metrics': 'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews,ga:users',
            'start-date': '365daysAgo',
            'end-date': 'today',
        }, 
        function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('getThisYearViewAnalytics failed: ' + error);
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(response);
            }
        });
    });
};

//ready, set, go!
go();
```

This is good progress, but I start running into authentication errors when attempting to [list accounts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accounts/list#request), with id(s) needed to list views (which also gives the same errors if you knew the account id).

I'm guessing that the answer is that I need to use OAuth, but if so, how? Is a service account no longer an option? I'm not sure how I would proceed with this when the service account and hardware device don't have usual OAuth back-and-forth user interaction to work with. Perhaps I'm just setting something wrong in the JWT Client being used above?

**UDPATE:**

Added info for those who read this in the future: After making sure read permissions were properly set, I was able to list Google Analytics accounts with this:

```
analytics.management.accounts.list({'auth': client}, function(error, response) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(response);
});
```

Note: This does not follow the promise pattern I was using above, but gives the idea of how node.js googleapis module works.

Comment: When you granted the service account access.  Did you do it at the account level?   It should not be having a problem reading the Accounts from management api.   Try this instead its faster https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list

Comment: also can you post the errors.

Comment: Aha! These are  authorized at view level. I'll test and post errors within the next hour. Thank you for this thought!

Comment: @DalmTo : After reviewing the [Google Analytics hierarchy](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009618?hl=en) and setting service account access to each Google Analytics account (not just the view), the errors went away. If you post post your comment in an answer format, I'll give you the points for sure. Thank you for the assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a service account with the Google Analytics api. You need to be sure that you add the permission at the account level. I don't know why it needs to be the account level I just know that it doesn't work right any other way.

Comment: This is correct. View queries can be made with view-specific permissions set (requiring manual entry of view ids in scripts). Getting lists of accounts, leading to lists of properties and views, requires the permissions to be set in the account, not just the view.

Comment: Btw if you release this project I would love the link

Comment: I'm happy to share, and will after I finish [this project](https://github.com/owntheweb/sos-orbiting-objects) first. Thank you for mentioning it.